# WebDriver Sampler in Jmeter - switch to new window, allow mic and cam in dialog box, perform actions, close new window, return back to initial window

Tags: javascript, jmeter, window, preferences, wds

I'm working on following scenario with WebDriver Sampler in Jmeter on javascript:

1. perform several requests in main window;
2. for 1 specific transaction:

   2.1. - switch from initial window to newly created window (both windows have the same title),

   2.2. - allow mic and cam (browser dialog box appears after new window is open and blocks activity of some page elements until cam and mic will not be allowed),

   2.3. - find elements on page and perform actions with them (I wrote javascript snippets for that),

   2.4. - close this 2nd window;
3. return back to initial main window;
4. proceed with requests in main window.

For steps 1 and 4 I have in js code all I need.

For step3, I suppose to use solution:

> //switch back to initial main window:
>
> WDS.browser.switchTo().defaultContent();

But I'm still stack on 2.1 and 2.2.

What is the best solution with 2.1, 2.2 and 2.4?

For 2.2. I tried to use "Set Preferences" section in Firefox WebDriver config and populate it with following:
[image]

Disadvantages:
1st - unfortunatelly, it doesn't work, and 2nd - I need these preferences working with Chrome, not only in FF.

Could you provide helpful tips, please, with 2.1, 2.2, 2.4?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this modal popup is a "window" controllable by WebDriver, it's rather a native window of the operating system hence you won't be able to interact with it using WebDriver functions, the options are in:

1. Simulate keyboard inputs using [java.awt.Robot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class
2. Locating the window using underlying operating system methods and sending the corresponding message to it, the entry point is [JNI](https://www.baeldung.com/jni)
3. Suppress these popups on browser startup level:

   - for Firefox you can [load a custom profile](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/firefox/FirefoxProfile.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.io.File)) with camera and mic allowed for the site you're testing
   - for Chromium and derivatives you can set the following [ChromeOptions](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities)

     - `use-fake-ui-for-media-stream`
     - `use-fake-device-for-media-stream`

   Unfortunately both approaches are not available out of the box for the [Firefox Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/FirefoxDriverConfig/) and [Chrome Driver Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/ChromeDriverConfig/) so you will have to switch to [JSR223 Sampler and Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black) for implementing your test scenario